# Either check if empty array, if not expect if it contain some value

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have an output `res.body.data`.

I can get an empty array if there is no data from the database, or if there is any, then I get a array of objects.
Then I need to check if each object contains an `id` field

How can achieve this in Jest?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Array.prototype.every` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
// This will check that the array is not empty
res.body.data.length > 0

// This will check that all the elements have an id
res.body.data.every((i) => i.id !== undefined && i.id !== null);
```